# Flutter Navigator 2.0: Add animation for RouterDelegate.setNewRoutePath

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, navigator

I am new to Flutter and currently trying to set up a navigation system for my first app. It works - I can switch between routes using `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()` or `Navigator.of(context).pop()` and I can change the navigation history using `RouterDelegate.setNewRoutePath()`. But when `setNewRoutePath` is called and the `RouterDelegate` rebuilds with a new value for `Navigator.pages`, no animation takes place when the new route is shown which makes the whole thing look inconsistent.
Is there a way to fix this?
I am using Flutter 2.5.3.

Below is my example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      routeInformationParser: AppRouteInformationParser(),
      routerDelegate: AppRouterDelegate(),
    );
  }
}

//Navigator 2.0 setup

//Config type
class AppRoute { 
  //This might be extended in the future to hold more data

  late String route;

  AppRoute(this.route);
}

//Parser
class AppRouteInformationParser extends RouteInformationParser<AppRoute>{
  @override
  Future<AppRoute> parseRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation) { 
    return SynchronousFuture(AppRoute(routeInformation.location ?? "/"));
  }
}

//Delegate 
class AppRouterDelegate extends RouterDelegate<AppRoute> { 
  var _navigationHistory = ValueNotifier<List<Page>>([MaterialPage(child: FirstPage())]);


  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _navigationHistory,
      builder: (context, history, child) {
        return Navigator(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          pages: (history ?? []) as List<Page>,
          onPopPage: (route, result) => route.didPop(result),
          onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
            switch (routeSettings.name) { 
              case "/subPage":
                return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage());
                break;
              case "/subPage/subPage":
                return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ThirdPage());
                break;
            }
            
          },
        );
      }
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> popRoute() { 

    return SynchronousFuture(true);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setNewRoutePath(AppRoute route) {
    switch (route.route) { 
      case "/subPage":
        _navigationHistory.value = [MaterialPage(child: FirstPage()), MaterialPage(child: SecondPage())];
        break;
      case "/subPage/subPage":
        _navigationHistory.value = [MaterialPage(child: FirstPage()), MaterialPage(child: SecondPage()), MaterialPage(child: ThirdPage())];
        break;
      default:
        _navigationHistory.value = [MaterialPage(child: FirstPage())];
    }
    
    return SynchronousFuture(null);
  }

  @override
  void addListener(VoidCallback listener) {}

  @override
  void removeListener(VoidCallback listener) {}
}


//Pages

class FirstPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build (context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text("Page 1"),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {Router.of(context).routerDelegate.setNewRoutePath(AppRoute("/subPage/subPage"));}, child: const Text("To page 3")),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/subPage");}, child: const Text("To next page")),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build (context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text("Page 2"),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pop();}, child: const Text("Go back")),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/subPage/subPage");}, child: const Text("To next page")),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class ThirdPage extends StatelessWidget {
    
    @override
    Widget build (context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const Text("Page 3"),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pop();}, child: const Text("Go back")),
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to see a solution to this, I have the same problem

Comment: @Finni I ended up doing a completely state-based implementation that ignores URLs using the `Router` widget, which works just fine, however, I did not go farther to find a solution that works in a browser.
You might want to take a look at [these examples](https://github.com/raywenderlich/flta-materials) (chapter 7 & 8) taken from a book that really helped me.

Comment: thanks for your reply, [this article](https://medium.com/geekculture/a-simpler-guide-to-flutter-navigator-2-0-part-ii-cf294d9dbe) helped me implement it by now